# How can I send plain text data/ JSON data instead of binary (opcode2) in secure websocket message of opentok

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I have a query, Is it possible to send plane text data instead of binary (opcode 2) in https://opentokdemo.tokbox.com.

I am trying  to understand the call flow of opentokdemo.tokbox.com , I am not able to read the websocket frame as it is in binary format. I tried with fiddler and wireshark as well but not decode properly .

Now I think if I make it possible, somehow i send the plain data over secure websocket by changing in opentok.js file.

IS there a way to do like this please suggest me any idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adam here from TokBox. There is no way that I know of to do that. The binary protocol is expected on the other end so even if you didn't send binary the other side would fail.

Perhaps I can help you though with what you're trying to do? Why are you trying to read the websocket messages?

Comment: Actually I want to simulate this call flow to our load testing tool for that I need to know what are the messages are flowing in the binary frame so that I can script the same message through our tool.
Although I proceed some extend where one end is our tool and other end is browser , in this scenario I am able listen the audio in browser side what I am sending in our tool but video part is showing black  "not able to see" am I missing something??

Comment: One thing I noticed there are 2 connection  while I am doing video conferencing 1. WSS and 2. WS  .
1. the link is "https://em005-lon.tokbox.com/rumorwebsocketsv2?socketId=" .
2.link is "https://opentokdemo-7b025.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5" .
1st link is used for media purpose but what is the perpose of the 2nd link?

Comment: The second link is using Firebase, it is used in opentokdemo for storage. It is not part of the OpenTok service.